# python csv problem- want to use variable in loc code

Tags: python, csv

I imported my csv file and I want to use variable in my loc code like\

```
a = 0; b = 1
df.loc[int(a+2),int(2*b-2)]
```

but it has an error
how do I fix it?

Comment: *but it has an error*, what error is it?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the value from position (a+2, 2*b-2), use `.iloc` instead.
`.loc` is used to select data from index name.

try this:

```py
df.iloc[a+2,2*b-2]
```

[pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use a slice of int numbers to select a piece of data. In pandas.DataFrame, you can use df.loc and df.iloc for indexing.

Allowed inputs of df.loc are:

- A single label, e.g. 5 or 'a', (note that 5 is interpreted as a label of the index, and never as an integer position along the index).
- A list or array of labels, e.g. ['a', 'b', 'c'].
- A slice object with labels, e.g. 'a':'f'.
- A boolean array of the same length as the axis being sliced, e.g. [True, False, True].
- An alignable boolean Series.
- An alignable Index.
- A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the above)

Allowed inputs of df.iloc are:

- An integer, e.g. 5.
- A list or array of integers, e.g. [4, 3, 0].
- A slice object with ints, e.g. 1:7.
- A boolean array.
- A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the above).

But both of them don't support two integers for inputing.

So maybe you should use df.iloc to accpet a list of integers `df.iloc[[int(a+2),int(2*b-2)]]`, instead of using df.loc `df.loc[int(a+2),int(2*b-2)]`.

For more details, you can see the documents:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html